# Drawing text in SlimDX with Directx 11?

Tags: fonts, slimdx, text

How can I draw text to the screen in directx 11 with slimdx?  In SlimDX.Direct3D10 there's a font class which can be used but there's no font class in SlimDX.Direct3D11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a bitmap font.  You create a table that maps each ASCII (or UTF) character code to a region of a texture that contains all the characters you want to use.  To draw a string, you create a vertex buffer with positions and textures, adding on a quad for each character, where the quad's size and UV coordinates are taken from the table.

[This page is a bit of a read](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut12.html), but it's quite an in-depth tutorial on bitmap fonts.

Comment: Is this the only way?  Seems much more complicated than the previous DirectX versions, why did they remove them?